# What's the correct way to map objects in RestKit with the following JSON response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

There's 2 parts to this question, both about RestKit:

1. How can we post up 2 values email and password, and deal with the response using the object mapper
2. How can we map 2 objects in a response

We are expecting the following JSON response:

```
{ 
    "code" : 0,
    "error_string" : "OK.",
    "message" : "OK.",
    "token" : { 
        "app_id" : "1",
        "created" : "2011-08-19 11:30:31",
        "token" : "ecb8862189974248233dfcc7e8fc1e4514e16972",
        "user_id" : "1"
    },
    "user" : { 
        "avatar_url" : "",
        "created" : "2011-08-19 11:29:21",
        "email" : "x@x.com",
        "forename" : "Matthew",
        "gender" : "M",
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to map this out, we've got a class setup for User and Token, but all the examples i've seen seem to not show something like this where there is two segments to the response, here's the code we have at the moment:

```
// Mapping for User
RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"created" toAttribute:@"created"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"avatar_url" toAttribute:@"avatarURL"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"gender" toAttribute:@"gender"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@"user"];

// Mapping for Token
RKObjectMapping* tokenMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Token class]];
[tokenMapping mapAttributes:@"user_id", @"app_id", @"token", @"created", nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:tokenMapping forKeyPath:@"token"];

// Load the object model via RestKit
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] setValue:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-API-KEY"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/users/authenticate/"  delegate:self];
```

Appreciate any help you can give on this, loving RestKit so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have everything you need configured for this mapping. You probably want to use the didLoadObjectDictionary: delegate call-back so that you can identify the objects by mappable keyPath. Otherwise if you use didLoadObjects:, you should just wind up with an Array with a User & Token object inside of it.